# How to make the component smaller when the frame is made smaller?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, layout-manager

How can I make the components in a frame (buttons, list .. etc) smoothly become smaller when the frame is reduced in size, considering that the components are inside more than one layout? The main one is `BorderLayout`.

Comment: You use layout managers that will resize components dynamically. If you use multiple panels with multiple layout manager then you need to understand how each component is resized within each layout manager. We can't tell you what to do because we have no ide what your exactly requirement is.

Comment: *"How to make the component smaller.."* Change the code. If you want our help with that.. 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Remove all the functionality (listeners etc.) & focus on the layout itself. If the list needs data to show the effect, either hard code some or use existing data obtained from the JRE (e.g. fonts or props)  2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.